# find elements in html DOM

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get Name/logo/Description/type from this HTML DOM 
I use python Beautiful Soup and got Description and Type
using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
for h in soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "description" }):
     print h.text
```

But Unable to get the Name and logo in a Json file.

```
<a href="/organization/flipkart">
    <div class="container organization_autocomplete">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://abcdsdsdsf/imm.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="identity container">
        <div class="follow_card_wrapper"><div class="link_container"><div class="name follow_card" data-name="Flipkart" data-type="Organization" data-uuid="43b9e775b843f194fb96d266684cfb53" data-permalink="/organization/flipkart" data-image="https://abcdsdsdsf/imm.jpg">Flipkart</div></div><div class="card_inner"></div></div>
        <div class="content container">
          <span class="type">Company - </span>
            <span class="description">
              Flipkart is an online shopping destination for electronics, books, music and movies.
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

I tried with the same method replacing Class name, but get empty output.
Can anyone tell how the Nested class be dealt in such cases

**EDIT**
I appreciate Alecxe efforts but Looking at alecxe's answer I have some confusions.

**It would be good if someone can explain that the classes where they
   have multiple name like**

```
<div class=container
   organization_autocomplete>
```

In this how to decide which one to use
   for selecting name container or organization_autocomplete and
   similarily for

- Also for let's say name why we didn't used these classes 
  class="follow_card_wrapper">
  class="name follow_card"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get both name and logo using the class attributes:

```
logo = soup.find("div", class_="logo").img["src"]
name = soup.find("div", class_="identity").find("div", class_="name").get_text()

print(logo, name)
```

Or, via [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
logo = soup.select_one("div.logo img")["src"]
name = soup.select_one("div.identity div.name").get_text()

print(logo, name)
```

As for choosing which classes to use, and which location techniques to apply in general - there is no silver bullet. Though, it is recommended to rely on ids and "data-oriented" classes or other data-oriented attributes. For instance, in your case, `container` class is more "layout"-oriented than "data"-oriented.

Comment: if I have multiple such html elements then replacing .find with .findAll should work, but it's not working?

Comment: @Prashant i that case, you should find all blocks first, via, say `for company in soup.find_all("div", class_="organization_autocomplete"):`. Then, for every company use the solution I've proposed, but replace `soup` with `company`.

Comment: that worked, but I get confuse in classes where they have multiple name like "<div class="container organization_autocomplete">" In this how to decide which one to use for selecting name container or organization_autocomplete and similarily for  <div class="identity container">

Comment: Also for let's say name why we didn't used these classes
<div class="follow_card_wrapper"><div class="link_container"><div class="name follow_card"

Comment: Can you please help me figure this out, because I always gets confused in such cases, It would be much better if you could add explaination in your answer itself

Comment: @Prashant sure, could you please create a separate question to keep this topic clean? Make sure to provide all the necessary details needed to answer. Thanks.

Comment: The further queries are related to same topic, please consider adding more details here itself, I had already added each and every detail in the question as well as comments

Comment: @Prashant ok, added some information to the answer. Hope that helps.